# Can clang static analysis be challenged with various flows

Tags: clang, static-analysis, clang++, llvm-clang, clang-static-analyzer

I wonder if currently there is support for clang static analysis with various flows checking. For example - there is a checker to check for zero division, but can clang find a flow which a divider can evaluate to zero ?
simple example: in the bellow example there is a flow (i=0) that b will evaluate to 0. do I get warning here ?

```
for(int i = 10; i>=0; i--){
   int a = div(i);
   ...
}

int div(int b){
   return 100000 / b;
}
```

if not, is there a plan to support this ?

Comment: what is function `div()` and where do you call function `foo()`?

Comment: you are right - fixed

Comment: Any reason you did not just try?

Comment: wanted to check first

Comment: I think we appreciate if you try to find a solution yourself upfront.